# How to use azuread credentials in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-active-directory

I have a jenkins server installed on ubuntu in our esx environment of office.
It is local VM, can be thought of.
How to use azuread for login to this jenkins?

Every employee has company email ID, which was created with azuread.
I want to use that instead of creating users again on this jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Azure credentials Within the Jenkins dashboard, click Credentials -> System ->. Click Global credentials(unrestricted). Click Add Credentials to add a Microsoft Azure service principal by filling out the Subscription ID, Client ID, Client Secret, and OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint. Provide an ID for use in subsequent step .

In Order to have Authentication and Authorization Via Azure Active Directory kindly check this [two](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-ad-plugin) [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli).